# How to mock an IFormFile for a unit/integration test in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to write tests for uploading of files in ASP.NET Core but can't seem to find a nice way to mock/instantiate an object derived from `IFormFile`.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Assuming you have a Controller like..

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public Task<IActionResult> UploadSingle(IFormFile file) {...}
}
```

...where the `IFormFile.OpenReadStream()` is accessed with the method under test.

As of ASP.NET Core 3.0, use an instance of the [FormFile Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile) which is now the default implementation of `IFormFile`.

Here is an example of the same test above using `FormFile` class

```
[TestClass]
public class IFormFileUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Should_Upload_Single_File() {
        //Arrange
       
        //Setup mock file using a memory stream
        var content = "Hello World from a Fake File";
        var fileName = "test.pdf";
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        //create FormFile with desired data
        IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "id_from_form", fileName);
        
        MyController sut = new MyController();
        
        //Act
        var result = await sut.UploadSingle(file);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IActionResult));
    }
}
```

Before the introduction of the [FormFile Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile) or in in cases where an instance is not needed you can create a test using [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq) mocking framework to simulate the stream data.

```
[TestClass]
public class IFormFileUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Should_Upload_Single_File() {
        //Arrange
        var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        //Setup mock file using a memory stream
        var content = "Hello World from a Fake File";
        var fileName = "test.pdf";
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);

        var sut = new MyController();
        var file = fileMock.Object;

        //Act
        var result = await sut.UploadSingle(file);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IActionResult));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 55):

Easier would be to create an actual in-memory instance

```
 var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a dummy file");
 IFormFile file = new FormFile(new MemoryStream(bytes), 0, bytes.Length, "Data", "dummy.txt");
```

Comment: Do you have a reference of where it existed before as shown in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile?view=aspnetcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to

Comment: This didn't work me, I mean the contents of the file could not be read. Instead I had to set length of the stream. I have stored the content of the file to a string variable named `content`. So the 3rd parameter of `FormFile` would be `content.Length`.

Comment: updated answer to set the correct length

Answer (score 21):

Adding on harishr's answer with a set lenght (which was what I needed for my Blob.Upload() to work).

```
private IFormFile CreateTestFormFile(string fileName, string content)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

    return new FormFile(
        baseStream: new MemoryStream(bytes),
        baseStreamOffset: 0,
        length: bytes.Length,
        name: "Data",
        fileName: fileName
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I could not mock the IFormFile, because I had problem with the Stream, so I end up with creating instance of FormFile. If you using validators etc. for the file be aware you need to set content type.

```
        private IFormFile GetFileMock(string contentType, string content)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

            var file = new FormFile(
                baseStream: new MemoryStream(bytes),
                baseStreamOffset: 0,
                length: bytes.Length,
                name: "Data",
                fileName: "dummy.csv"
            )
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = contentType
            };

            return file;
        }
```

to call

```
 GetFileMock("text/csv", "test;test;")
```

Comment: I was having stream issues to, and your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static IFormFileCollection GetFormFileCollection()
{
    var filesFolder = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase}UploadFiles\\";
    List<string> filesPathsListToUpload = new List<string>();
    filesPathsListToUpload.Add($"{filesFolder}UploadFile1.png");
    filesPathsListToUpload.Add($"{filesFolder}UploadFile2.jpg");
    filesPathsListToUpload.Add($"{filesFolder}UploadFile3.bmp");

    FormFileCollection filesCollection = new FormFileCollection();
    foreach (var filePath in filesPathsListToUpload)
    {
        var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "files", Path.GetFileName(filePath))
        {
            Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
            ContentType = filePath.Split('.')[1] == "jpg" ? "image/jpeg"
                : filePath.Split('.')[1] == "png" ? "image/png"
                : "image/bmp",
        };
        
        filesCollection.Add(file);
    }

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    httpContext.Request.Form = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>(), filesCollection);

    return httpContext.Request.Form.Files;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, don't just put a block of code down ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this nippet for my intergration tests

```
public static MultipartFormDataContent CreateTestFile(string fileName, string fileContent)
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent)), "files", fileName);
            return content;
        }
```

And thats how I use it with my [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-webapplicationfactory)

```
[Fact]
        public async Task UploadDocument_ReturnsOk()
        {
            // Arrange
            var provider = TestClaimsProvider.WithUserClaims();
            var client = _factory.CreateClientWithTestAuth(provider);

            // Act
            HttpResponseMessage? resultResponseMessage = await client.PutAsync($"/api/Documents",
                WebApiExtensions.CreateTestFile("test.csv", "content"));

            // Assert
            resultResponseMessage.ShouldHave200Code();
        }
```