# How to call a function which accepts IFormFile without using Mocking framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, iformfile

I am trying to call a controller which looks like below:

```
Task<IActionResult> Create(List<IFormFile> RunFiles)
```

Now, I am just trying to figure out what is the easiest way to pass it that list of `IFormFiles`

```
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("\\run1\\IHW01018Exp049HLAMicro_S13_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"));
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "Fastq.fastq"
};

formData.Add(fileContent, "FastQ");

var response = await client.PostAsync($"run", formData);
```

I thought this would at least be recognized as a valid `IFormfile` but what is happening here is basically, it is calling the method without throwing any errors. However, `RunFiles` parameters has 0 members. So basically an emptylist of `IFormFile`.

I looked around web and came across this post :

[How to mock an IFormFile for a unit/integration test in ASP.NET Core 1 MVC 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858542/how-to-mock-an-iformfile-for-a-unit-integration-test-in-asp-net-core-1-mvc-6)

Which basically suggested to use Moq.Well, guess what, we do not have Moq in our framework. However, it brings  me back to my original question that is there any way to call function like this for UnitTesting/Integration Testing without relying on external frameworks like MOQ? Or am I doing something wrong in existing code?

Comment: You do realize that `RunFiles` is a list of `IFormFile` but you're just passing on a single object, right? At first, you should try to wrap your single object on an array

Comment: Furthermore, you're not even calling an HTTP endpoint. What's `$"run"` ?

Comment: No,HTTP endpoint is being called correctly and is recieving the request on the other end.

Comment: I edited my code after trying `MultipartFormDataContent` but seems like that is also not working.