# How can I Mock a File Upload in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I have written a code for uploading a file to a cloud storage. That code consist of a post method which takes a file in the format : multipart/form-data and uploads it to cloud. So how can I write a test case for the same? To be specific, how to mock that post file.

The format used is  formfile
The code is in asp.net core 3.1 using c#.

Comment: Why not change it to `IFormFile` and then mock `IFormFile`?

Comment: refer this link for mock an IFormFile for a unit/integration test in ASP.NET Core  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858542/how-to-mock-an-iformfile-for-a-unit-integration-test-in-asp-net-core-1-mvc-6)

Answer (score 2):

i suggest the use of abstraction here , you should create an interface like Below -

```
Public Interface IFileSystem{
 bool uploadFile(FileStrem fileContent);
}
```

and then write your cloud specific implementation in a derivation from above class and

in your buisness logic use that implementation , so that when you write tests for buisness logic you can mock the FileSystem.

Comment: As far as I can tell OP is asking how to mock the file they receive (that was HTTP POSTed) rather than the upload to the cloud. I might be mistaken though.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica I can imaging that there is method that uploads file. So to test it you have to call this method but you do not have to upload file actually. This means that file uploading code must be refactored with certain `ICloud.UploadFile`. Then `ICloud` can be mocked and test can be created

Comment: @oleksa My point was that it doesn't seem to be the part that OP is wanting to test.

Answer (score 2):

In the companies where I worked, 'Mocking' has never really seen too well.

Usually writing a test implementation works better:

```
public interface IUploader
{
    IResult Upload(string filePath);
}

public sealed class FileUploader
{
    IResult Upload(string filePath) { ... } // method is implemented as expected
}

public sealed class TestUploader //this is placed in a specific folder for test implementations
{
    public IResult ExpectedResult { get; set; } = Result.Success();
    IResult Upload(string filePath) => ExpectedResult;
}
```

To connect it with your class check the *Humble Object Design Pattern*. It explains how to extract testable logic from apparently untestable classes.

```
void UploadToCloud(string filePath) 
{
    ...
    Uploader.Upload(filePath); // real implementation in production code, test implementation during unit testing.
    ...
}
```

I'd prefer going this way for multiple reasons:

- A change in the production code forces you to change the test implementation as well. With a Mock you would risk not to notice that your tests became obsolete.
- A test implementation gives you more freedom (i.e. you can pass the test result to the test implementation in the initialization part of the test, to check edge cases).
- It is cleaner than mocks and other developers can understand better what is going on. The tidier the code, the easier it is to keep it clean.
- You still have some constraints given from the interface. Sometimes the Mock classes just become huge monsters that do not look like the original class anymore.

**NOTE**: If you want to test the receiving part, you can use the same strategy. Your test implementation will contain the expected content of the file, to test the cloud response.