# File Path for Data in my project wont work

Tags: c#, file, nunit, moq

I am building a web API that receives a CSV file through a post request. It comes in the form of an `IFormFile`.

I want to unit test my post method and I found the only way to mock the `IFormFIle` that I am sending into the post method. I have created A folder in my unit test project called `Data` which stores the CSV file (`Meter_Reading.csv`). I have set the properties of my file to be an `Embedded Resource`.

Here is my code to test the method:

```
[Fact]
public void HasCorrectImageType()
{
    var formFile =  new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var PhysicalFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\eak\source\repos\MeterReadings\MeterReadings.Core.Tests\Data\Meter_Reading.csv");
    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(memory);
    writer.Write(PhysicalFile.OpenRead());
    writer.Flush();
    memory.Position = 0;
    var fileName = PhysicalFile.Name;

    formFile.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
    formFile.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(memory.Length);
    formFile.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(memory);
    formFile.Verify();

    var controller = new ScanController();
    var file = formFile.Object;

    var result = controller.Scan(file);
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OkObjectResult>(result);
}
```

My problem is the Physical file path. I am having to use the full path as shown above in order to get it to work. I have tried these to shorten the file path to a relative path:

```
 @"..\\Data\\Meter_Reading.csv"
```

or

```
string fileName = "ich_will.mp3";
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", fileName);
```

Nothing works but the full file path. I can't use that file path as should the application be used by another developer on their machine, it wont work. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the subject under test as well please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock an IFormFile for a unit/integration test in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858542/how-to-mock-an-iformfile-for-a-unit-integration-test-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **IHostingEnvironment**

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
public constructorName(IHostingEnvironment environment){
 _environment = environment;
}
string fileName = "ich_will.mp3";
var path = _environment.ContentRootPath + "\\Data\\" + fileName;
```

Comment: My code doesn't even run with this amendment sorry.